# python - what is max byte equivalent to java Byte.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, python, hbase

Does python have an equivalence to java's `Byte.MAX_VALUE` representing the max byte? I had a look at python `sys` module, I only managed to find `sys.maxint`. Does it have anything like `sys.maxbyte`?

UPDATE:

In my case, I am doing a Hbase Rowkey scan, My rowkey looks like rk1_rk2. In order to scan all results for rk1 without knowing exact rk2, My java code looks like:

```
byte[] startRowBytes = "rk1".getBytes(); 
byte[] endRowBytes = ("rk1" + (char) Byte.MAX_VALUE).getBytes(); 

HbaseScanQuery query = new   HbaseScanQuery(tableName, colFamily);
query.setStartRow(startRowBytes).setStopRow(endRowBytes);
```

I am just trying to work out the python equivalence of Byte.MAX_VALUE part.

Comment: Bytes are always max hex FF; decimal 255. What do you need this for? This is not a value that'll change from platform to platform, so it's not worth adding to `sys` for.

Comment: It looks like it's only a constant(value =127), so there's no need of anything like `sys.maxbyte`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Byte.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Java Bytes are signed integers, that's different from Python `bytes` and `bytesarray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to define the value yourself. A byte has 2^8 = 256 unique states and so the largest integer it can represent is 255. java's byte type, however, is a signed byte, so half the states are reserved for positives(and 0) and the other half is used for negatives. therefore the the equivalent of java's Byte.MAX_VALUE is 127, and the equivalent of java's Byte.MIN_VALUE is -128

Since python bytes are unsigned, the equivalent of java's Byte.MIN_VALUE would be 128 which is the representation of -128 in 2's compliment notation(the defacto standard for representing signed integers) thanks to  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for pointing that out.

I haven't dealt with python in a while, but i believe what you want is ("rk1"+chr(127))

Comment: Except negative values are invalid for purposes of creating a `bytes`.

Comment: ok, but the representation can be the same in the underlying byte regardless of whether it is signed or not, so ill edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: @AaronWaibel can you give a code example to translate this in python : ("rk1" + (char) Byte.MAX_VALUE).getBytes(), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given your update, there is an even better answer:  Don't worry about what the max byte value is.  According to the [HBase documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book/data_model_operations.html), the `setStartRow` and `setStopRow` methods work just like Python's slicing; namely, the start is inclusive, but the stop is **exclusive**, meaning your `endRowBytes` should simply be `'rk2'`.

Also, the documentation mentions that you can make the stop row inclusive by adding a **zero** byte, so another alternative is `'rk1' + chr(0)` (or `'rk1\0'` or `'rk1\x00'`, whichever is clearest to you).  In fact, the example used to explain HBase scans in the linked documentation illustrates exactly your use case.